# Add import using code model

Tags: java, sun-codemodel, jcodemodel

I am trying to **import** a class in my code using **code model**.
This is my code.

```
JCodeModel model = new JCodeModel();
JClass mapper = model.directClass("com.another.Mapper");
JDefinedClass dc = model._class("com.example.Something");
JMethod method = dc.method(JMod.PUBLIC | JMod.STATIC, Void.TYPE,
        "testMethod");
JBlock executerBlock = method.body();
    executerBlock.directStatement("Mapper.get()");
File file = new File("./src");
file.mkdirs();
model.build(file);
```

Now I am getting the following class as result.

```
package com.example;
public class Something {
    public static void testMethod() {
    Mapper.get()
    }
}
```

But actually i need is,

```
package com.example;
import com.another.Mapper;
public class Something {
    public static void testMethod() {
    Mapper.get()
    }
}
```

The import is not coming unless it use. How can i possible to make this import.

Comment: If the import is not used, it is not in .class.  Here is the tool is creating correct source code. Looks like a feature. Why do you want in other way?

Comment: @Jayan  I am using JBlock.directStatement() method. Inside that i am using this class.(updated in question).

Answer (score 0):

For `Mapper` to be added as an import, you will need to call `invoke()` / `staticInvoke()` instead of `directStatement()`:

```
JClass mapper = model.directClass("com.another.Mapper");
JDefinedClass dc = model._class("com.example.Something");
JMethod method = dc.method(JMod.PUBLIC | JMod.STATIC, Void.TYPE, "testMethod");
JBlock executerBlock = method.body();
executerBlock.staticInvoke(mapper, "get");
```